# How to automatically project texture from high poly mesh to low poly mesh?

Tags: texture, 3d, diffuse, 3dtexture

I have two aligned meshes: I have exact mapping from each vertex of low poly mesh to surface of a high poly mesh. High poly (~100K vertices) mesh is non-manifold, low poly (~1K vertices) is manifold and allows cylindrical texture mapping and each vertex has a normal.

What algorithms can I use to project supersampled texture (albedo/diffuse and normal maps) from high poly mesh to low poly mesh? It would be great to have not only a paper, but implementation as well.

Comment: It would be much preferable you'd ask for an actual *algorithm* to do that, as this is more what this site is for, rather than advice for what software to use. The general problem is interesting, but we don't really do software recommendation here.

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks for your note! I've edited the question.

Comment: Also note that there is a [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Perhaps your original question would be appropriate there? (I'd check the FAQ first to be sure.)